# Entity Framework FirstOrDefault overrides with constructor values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have a User model with a constructor method - User(). When I use EF to retrieve a user from database, EF returns the value from the constructor instead of the value from database. My User class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set;}
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set;}

    public User()
    {
        PasswordSalt = "some random value"
    }
 }
```

Retrieving the user:

```
var user = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Email == "a@b.com");
```

As a result, user.PasswordHash will return "some random value" instead of the hash actually stored in database.

Comment: How about using a default value when creating the model. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values

Comment: The password salt value here implies that each user receives a uniquely generated random value. If i understand the concept of default values correctly, that seems to render a static value.

Comment: Can't reproduce this - I can set default values in the constructor, but if a row is found in the database, those values will be returned - not the constructor defaults. There must be something more going on here.......

Comment: @marc_s You are correct something was wrong in my code. The class has a setter function that generated a new hash when assigning a value to the property (this method is not shown in code above). It seems EF applies the setter function even though the value is coming from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

We have to change constructor as below

```
 public class User
{
public string Email { get; set;}
public string PasswordSalt { get; set;}

public User()
{
    PasswordSalt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordSalt)? "some random value":PasswordSalt;
}
}
```